# When should we use '=== ' operator in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When and why should we use '===' in javascript or jquery.
Is it recommended to test string using === and if yes why. 
I have a code where i am checking a condition on the string like.
if(a == "some-thing") is this right or should i use '==='

Answer (score 1):

`===` means exactly equal - compare value and type.

```
'1' == 1 // true
'1' === 1 // false
```

Answer (score 0):

`===` is used for strictly type check, when you want to check value as well as its type.
For Example

```js
var x = 5;
var y = "5";
var z=5;
alert(x==y);//string and int value same though type different - TRUE
alert(x===y);//value same but type different - FALSE
alert(x===z);//value same and type same- TRUE
```

**[More Information](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp)**

Answer (score 0):

with `===` you will compare the value AND the type of data. With `==` you only compare the value. So `1000 == "1000"` it's true, while `1000 === "1000"` is false.

Answer (score 0):

In a simple answer:

Triple equals does a check for type equality. So it'll check the types as well as the contents.

e.g.

```
var a = '1' === 1;
```

Would be false.

A double equals would only check the contents, so the code above would return true.

Answer (score 0):

As a good practice, as much as possible.

As a minimum : if you want to check specifically for 0/false/null value because when you use `==` they're all the same :

```
0 == false // true
0 === false // false
```

And f you test the existence of a value but that value can be false or 0 this won't work.

```
if(value){} // false is value === false or value === 0
```

There is also the type equality but i don't really think that much relevant unless you depend on some 3rd-party where you need this.

Answer (score 0):

A === "some string" means equal value and moreover equal type.

It's a double test: In your case you obtain true not simply if the values are equal but moreover if the variable A is a string.

Answer (score -3):

You should **almost always** use the === operator.

An example why:

```
1 == '1' //is true
1 === '1' //is false
```

And you want to achieve the second result, because === checks if also the type is the same.

Comment: Not always. That's not true

Comment: What if from GET you receive string and from databse you receive integer? Same values, but `===` will ruin things

Comment: Why do you always need to check the type? JavaScript is not type sensitive and the function is added for a reason.